# Weird strcmp returns in C

Tags: c, strcmp

Why is this code printing 202? The ascii value of 'e' is 101 and that of null character is 0. So shouldn't it print 101?

But when I interchange s1 and s2, I do get -101 as the answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s1[50] = "ape";
    char s2[50] = "ap";
    printf("%d ", strcmp(s1, s2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you read that it is defined to return 101 in that case? The [strcmp manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) makes no such claim. `strcmp` is only defined to return "an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero". The exact value returned is implementation depdendent. FWIW, I do get 101 when I run it in on my Ubuntu Linux system. So maybe your libc implementation is doing something different (but still valid) in that case and it would be helpful if you provided your system info.

Comment: The print returns 1. Where is the 101 came from? and if you reverse them it gives -1
And if they would match it is ZERO. Please read more about `strcmp()` https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp

Comment: Generally whenever I use strcmp, it returns the difference in the ascii value of the first 2 different characters in the strings. So I thought that it should return 101.

Comment: GAREER, if you want a function to do that (in a guaranteed way), you'll have to write it yourself :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah I was just thinking how strcmp actually works

Comment: @GAREER "whenever I use strcmp, it returns the difference in the ascii value of the first 2 different characters in the strings" --> Rather than learn a function's return values by experience, faster to learn by reviewing its specification.  Your choice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I just found it confusing that every other time it was returning the ascii difference of the first non matching pair but only in this kind of situation it does not.

Comment: APIs don't work as you _think_ they work. They work as _documented_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky wise words indeed

Answer (score 6):

> "So shouldn't it print 101?"

No. `strcmp()` only needs to return some positive value in this case.

> The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.